# Constructing regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to construct a regular expression in order to validate a string with `Oval`.
I got lost in all the signs and expression.
I want my string not to contain certain words at the beginning and doesn't contain some special words.
Like for example I want to exclude the words `ignoreMe1`,`ignoreMe2`,`ignoreMe3`at the beginning of the string and exclude `?;*/`.
I tried to do this as start : `^(?!ignoreMe1|ignoreMe2|ignoreMe3)` but it doesn't work.
How to proceed?

Comment: How about checking for every keyword you want to exclude first (use regex or `indexOf`)... and for every keyword you want to include in a second step? There is no need to cram everything into one regular expression. A two-step approach is perfectly all-right here.

Comment: @Tomalak I can't I need to do this in one shot in Oval

Comment: It's rather hard to imagine that OVal isn't flexible enough to do this in several steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match anything that doesn't start with ignoreMe1/2/3 and does not contain any of those symbols

```
^(?!ignoreMe1|ignoreMe2|ignoreMe3)[^?;*/]+$
```

See [example here](http://regex101.com/r/tT5uA3)